# How do you globally configure moment.js in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

After adding `moment.js` to my project.
to use it in components i'm required to first import it.

```
import * as moment from 'moment';
```

and then on every component, I create an empty variable, and initialize the same configurations on ngOnInit()

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

   moment: any;

   ngOnInit() {
      moment.locale('ar');
      this.moment = moment;
    }
}
```

I find myself copy-pasting this code everywhere.
is it possible to do it only once ? at least the configurations `moment.locale()` and such ?

Answer (score 4):

> at least the configurations moment.locale()

You only need to do it once.

```
import * as moment from 'moment';
moment.locale(); // impacts *all* imports of moment from this point forward.
```

> I find myself copy-pasting this code everywhere

You should only be copy pasting `import * as moment from 'moment';`. This is a good thing as you have a clear record of where moment is used in your project.